# Why after start build all files deleted in my directory job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

A very strange situation.
After starting the assembly, all files in the folder are deleted and file cloning starts again.

As a rule, after starting the build, Jenkins completely deleted the folder with the downloaded files and downloaded them again.

Given that the repository weighs 25 gigs, it took a lot of time to download

Such cases have gone by and how did you manage to solve this situation?

I use: 
1) pipeline jenkins
2) My git repo 25G

```
steps {
    dir('My_1_Folder_Repo') {
        checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: '*/master']],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
        extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch'],[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 120]],
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '*', url: '*.git']]
        ])
    }
    dir('My_2_Folder_Repo') {
        checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: '*/master']],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
        extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch'],[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 120]],
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '*', url: 'ssh://git@*/*.git']]
        ])
    }
    dir('My_3_Folder_Repo') {
        checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: "${params.BRANCH_SELECTOR}"]],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
        extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch'],[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 600]],
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '*',  url: 'https://*.git']]
        ])
    }
    dir('My_4_Folder_Repo') {
        checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: "${params.BRANCH_SELECTOR}"]],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
        extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch'],[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 300]],
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '*',  url: '*.git']]
        ])
}
```

Comment: In Pipeline code you have mentioned Clean Up Process before the build starts. ' [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 120]],'. By deleting it you can continue with the existing files.

Comment: @ZERG: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following in your code: `[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']`

With that in place, Jenkins will clean up the workspace each time it checks out the code. Just remove that portion and you should be good.

From the [official reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/):

---

$class: CleanBeforeCheckout

Clean up the workspace before every checkout by deleting all untracked files and directories, including those which are specified in .gitignore. It also resets all tracked files to their versioned state. This ensures that the workspace is in the same state as if you cloned and checked out in a brand-new empty directory, and ensures that your build is not affected by the files generated by the previous build.

---

Note: In cases where the code size is not that significant, it's usually a good practice to have `[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']` enabled to avoid *unexpected* issues arising from leftover files in your workspace by the last build.